# How to set text in multiple columns?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

How to can put the text in two columns, for example (A1:B1 , 'hello world')?

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'Hola a todos !');

$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, 7, 'Prueba');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('excel/hello world.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `MergeCells` to join two columns

`$sheet->MergeCells('A1:B1');`

and you just put text at first column you join 
`$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');` 
`$sheet->MergeCells('A1:B1');`

Comment: Sorry my english.
A lot of thanks, it is very kind.